# Python shutil - copy file + file tree for specific file only

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to copy files from list with shutil and place them in same folder structure in another directory:

```
import os
import shutil

src = "/sourcedoc/1/"
dest = "/destdoc/"

files_to_find = []
with open('filelist.txt') as fh:
    for row in fh:
        files_to_find.append(row.strip())

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for _file in files:
        if _file in files_to_find:
            print('Found file in: ' + str(root))
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest), exist_ok = True)
            shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + _file), dest + _file)
```

I want to create the folders with the same names as the ones containing the files that are to be copied in the new destination and then copy the files in them.
The final goal is to have structure like "/destdoc/1/" and having copied the files from the list. However, what I get is all the files in the destination directory without the folder structure. It seems that using shutil.copytree copies all of the files in the folders.

Comment: That is because according to your code you are working with the files themselves and not the folders. If you are strictly working with the files the way you are doing while ignoring the folders they are in you cannot expect to get anything that is not a file

Comment: I see. To copy the dirs I will have to replace  for _file in files with for dir in dirs, but how would I copy the files to the newly created folders then ?